# Getting "Proxy authentication Required" message while installing a perl module from CPAN

Tags: linux, perl, cpan

I'm trying to install a Perl module (JSON) from CPAN but getting below error.

```
root@catspc:/etc/apt# cpan

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.960001)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> install JSON
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sat, 07 Dec 2013 22:53:04 GMT
Fetching with LWP:
http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz

Proxy authentication needed!
 (Note: to permanently configure username and password run
   o conf proxy_user your_username
   o conf proxy_pass your_password
     )
Username:  vc06
Password:  

Catching error: "Undefined subroutine &CPAN::HTTP::Credentials::_clear_non_proxy_credentials called at /usr/share/perl/5.14/CPAN/HTTP/Credentials.pm line 10, <STDIN> line 2.\cJ" at /usr/share/perl/5.14/CPAN.pm line 391
    CPAN::shell() called at /usr/share/perl/5.14/App/Cpan.pm line 295
    App::Cpan::_process_options('App::Cpan') called at /usr/share/perl/5.14/App/Cpan.pm line 364
    App::Cpan::run('App::Cpan') called at /usr/bin/cpan line 11
Fetching with LWP:
http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Lockfile removed.
Undefined subroutine &CPAN::HTTP::Credentials::_clear_non_proxy_credentials called at /usr/share/perl/5.14/CPAN/HTTP/Credentials.pm line 10, <STDIN> line 2.
root@catspc:/etc/apt#
```

Could someone help me in fixing this issue? What went wrong here?

Awaiting your valuable reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are your cpan configuration is skewed.

Is there a reason why you dont use cpanm? (https://metacpan.org/release/App-cpanminus)

I switched from cpan to cpanm some years ago and havent regretted it yet.

> DESCRIPTION
>
> cpanminus is a script to get, unpack, build and install modules from
>   CPAN and does nothing else.
>
> It's dependency free (can bootstrap itself), requires zero
>   configuration, and stands alone. When running, it requires only 10MB
>   of RAM.

Comment: Yes, it did work and is simple to download the modules.